# Is Backbone better choice for beginners than AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, backbone.js, angularjs

The last couple of years I've spent working in Flex. Before that I've been building web applications in vanilla JavaScript.

Today I'm switching back to JavaScript but now I'm having trouble in choosing the right JS framework/library for a new medium-size project.

Although all the comments on AngularJS have been positive, I found that getting started with it is not an easy task. The problem is of course the documentation. Although there are tutorials which show you how to do the basic stuff, none explain the concepts or show you how one might structure larger projects.

Before discovering AngularJS I had my mind set at Backbone. The positive side is that there are loads of documentation, tutorials, screencasts, books on the subject. In addition the source code is small and can be used as a reference itself (unlike AngularJS).

So now I'm thinking that Backbone might a better choice for someone who's getting stared with using frameworks in JS programming than AngularJS. Later on, when I manage to train my brain to think in JS, AngularJS might be easier to understand + there will be more documentation available.

I'm now in doubt if that's the right path to choose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure that switching to JavaScript was the right choice.

Selecting a JavaScript MVC framework is indeed a difficult choice, especially because they're popping like popcorns everywhere!

This project might be very helpful regarding this decision: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/

Here is my point of view. Backbone is liberal. It does not impose a rigid structure. It is more a set of conventions than actual code. You will certainly be using something more than just the Backbone framework. This can be challenging, but may result in a better tuned result. Backbone is very extensible by nature, which is a great advantage.

AngularJS augments HTML semantics. Just by saying this you can imagine that it is something much more complex than just "pure" Backbone. Perhaps we may find AngularJS a bit more magical (not magical of course, but things happening with less code, "under the hood", I mean).

They have very different approaches to the problem.
I'm not going to state here every advantage and disadvantage of each one. The link I posted should help you on that.
I too was confused like you, but in short, investigate both, make some spike implementations with both, and check the todoMVC project. Choose wichever suits better your requirements and even personality. :)

A much more fairer comparison could be "Backbone and friends" vs "AngularJS". Don't forget Backbone's friends (plugins and modules).

You can do great things with both.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the end I started using Backbone + Backbone.stickit + Underscore + jQuery + RequireJS (this list is probably going to expand in the future).

I must say that starting with Backbone and friends was much more straight forward than my attempts to understand Angular. The key factor here is probably because Backbone itself is really simple, so the amount of stuff you need to understand is minimal - the concept is simple. Later on you can when you need to add something, you just choose another library for the task (i.e. UnderscoreJS).

Comment: On the other hand to start using Angular in a real-life project you need to understand much more ... invest more time and effort. There are some tutorials and a reference manual, but I haven't found any document which would explain the concepts.

So I think I'll stick with Backbone for now ... at least until there's some decent documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been there past few days. I've implemented a simple CRUD over REST api in both frameworks. Here are my thoughs:

Angular is harder, because it's convention over configuration, new concepts like directives and such, you need to think with extending HTML instead of javascript hacking (which can be not that difficult for flex practitioners).

But in the end I prefer it because it does more than backbone out of the box. You don't need to write jquery stuff. The templating is way more readable than using Backbone and underscore templating. There is less code (easier to maintain), and I like the way I can have a component approach for structuring my clientside code.

Comment: I can see your point, but the argument of not choosing Backbone because of the need to write jquery isn't entirely valid. First because it may be an advantage to some people (some might be more familiar with it) and then because there are options which don't involve writing jquery (i.e., Model Binding https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding). Probably not as elegant as AngularJS packaged approach, I not really into it.

Comment: yeah I'm not arguing there, just exposing my overall experience.